# Is there any event to know if a view is moved below some other view?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a stack of views shown on top of each other. So at a time only 1 view is shown and others are below the active view. I want to know whether a particular view is active or moved below some other view inside the `ViewPart` code. Is there any listener which can tell me that the composites of any view are now moved below some other composites of another view?

Also it would be great if can I know through listeners that a particular view is now made invisible.
I have only access to my view code and that is why I have to implement it in that view only.
Stack of views is shown under one `Window` so the parent shell is same of all the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener` to listen for events about parts.

In a `ViewPart` you can use:

```
getSite().getPage().addPartListener(partListener);
```

to add a listener. The listener has method for parts being opened, closed, activated and deactivated and brought to the top of  stack.

You can also use `IPartListener2` which has some additional methods.

Comment: I think IPartListener2 ist pretty much what he needs.

Comment: Yes, IPartListener2 is working great for my requirement. Thanks @greg-449